# Error when "import requests" - "No module named requests"

Tags: python, python-requests

N00b Altert.

So I tried to call "import requests" through Python and got the error:

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I do not think I have pip installed correctly or at all?

easy_install requests returns:
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-6488.pth'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated... I have seen the other posts with users mentioning the same but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What OS are you running? Are you sure pip isn't installed? If you're on *nix, try just running `sudo pip install requests`

Comment: You seem to be running OS X. Have you tried `brew install pip`, then `pip install requests`?

Comment: Mac OS Capitan. @SeanPianka ran `brew install pip` response: `Error: No available formula with the name "pip" 
Homebrew provides pip via: `brew install python`. However you will then
have two Pythons installed on your Mac, so alternatively you can install
pip via the instructions at:
  https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/`

Comment: What about `python -m pip install requests`?

Comment: Thanks, executed, returned: `No module named pip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [requests website installation page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#install):

1. Checkout the [git repository](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests)
2. execute `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python requests/setup.py install`

As a third step, if you have problems doing this, please come back and leave a comment, such that I may help you further.

Your problem is a permissions problem. The solution I'd recommend is to `pip install virtualenv` and create a new environment for your project, installing requests in that environment.

To install pip, do a `curl -kO https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` and run it as `python get-pip.py` then install virtualenv as in the above paragraph.

Comment: This is a good platform independent solution (+1), but just as a note, for new programmers getting Pip up is usually a much easier and faster solution.

Comment: .... and also requires installation of pip. For most libraries, running setup.py directly works. But, your point is a good one.

Comment: Please see [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) for pip installation information, I've edited my answer with the tl;dr of it.

Comment: Solved, and installed requests. `sudo python get-pip.py` then executed `sudo pip install requests` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
import requests
```

Guide your cursor to the command (Donot press space) You will see a red bulb.There will be an option to install requests. Click it and done. 
This worked for me on **Pycharm**. Installing it through pip didnot help me.